# Create a new data type ('a,'b)myList with different types at its ends

Tags: sml

How can I create a new data type `('a, 'b) myList` that starts only with `type1`, and end only with `type2`?

For example :

```
[4,5,6,8,9.3,4.2,5.1]        (*starts with int ends with real*)
[“hi”, “hello”, true, false] (*starts with string ends with bool*)
[4,5,6,8,9.3,4.2,5]          (*can't because starts with int and ends with int*)
```

Comment: What operations do you want to be able to do with this list? Typically, you build up a list recursively by adding a new element to the head of another list. You won't be able to do that with your proposed strangely typed list, as what would a list with 1 element look like?

Answer (score 2):

First note that `[]` always creates values of type `list`, so defining your own types won't change the fact that you can only use one type within `[]`. So if that's your goal, you won't be able to accomplish it.

What you could do is to simply define `myList` to contain one value of type `'a` (the first element), an `('a 'b alternative) list` and a value of type `'b` (the last element), where `'a 'b alternative` is a type that you define so that it can contain either an `'a` or a `'b`.

Then you could create `myList`s by writing something like `MyList ("hi", [B true, B false, A "hello", B true], false)`.

Comment: maybe i have not been so clear about the examples

the only condition is that the list starts with type1 and end in type2

meaning i can do this [“hi”,true, false,“hello”, true, false]
you solution only allows me to do two separated lists one of type1 and the other of type2 and combine them

Comment: @user2525235 Ah, I assumed that once an element of type `'b` occurs, no element of type `'a` is allowed anymore. But you're saying the only requirement is that the very first element is an `'a` and the very last is a `'b` and all others can be either `'a` or `'b` without restriction? Then I misunderstood.

Comment: @user2525235 Am I correct in assuming then, that every `myList` must have at least 2 arguments?

Comment: @user2525235 I edited my answer to hopefully address what you want.

Comment: that is exactly what i meant  the very first element is an 'a and the very last is a 'b and all others can be either 'a or 'b without restriction.

my list can build this  
Type1 (4, Type1 (5, Type1 (6, Type2 (9.3, Type2 (4.2, Nil)))));
but cant build this 
Type1 (4, Type2 (5.3, Type1 (6, Nil)));

so there is no assumptions, it cant build a list which consists of one element because it doesn't meet the requirements
thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant, but you could do something like this

```
datatype ('a, 'b) union = A of 'a 
                        | B of 'b;
abstype ('a,'b) mylist = MyList of 'a * ('a, 'b) union list * 'b
with
    fun Create (a,b) = MyList(a, [], b);
    fun Hd (MyList(a,_,_)) = a;
    fun Cons a1 (MyList(a2, middle, b)) = MyList(a1, (A a2) :: middle, b);
    fun ConsMiddle AorB (MyList(a, middle, b)) = MyList(a, AorB :: middle, b);
end;
```

You create a list by supplying a `'a` for the start and a `'b` for the end. 
You can then build up the list by inserting a `'a` at the start, or inserting either a `'a` or a `'b` immediately after the start (preserving your required type invariant).